# searched in the `iFrame` by clicking the `search me` button on the site with js

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an `iFrame` that shows the `TradingView`  site.

I wanted the text I  write in the `Input` to be searched in the `iFrame` by clicking the `search me` button on the TradingView chart.
Friends, the `function` I wrote does not work can you guide me what to do?

```js
function test() {
document.getElementById('tradingview_82512').contentDocument.getElementById("#header-toolbar-symbol-search > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)").value=document.getElementById("in01").value
document.getElementById('fram').contentDocument.querySelector("#sb_form > label").click()
}
```

```css
#fram{
width:600px;
height:150px
}
button{
height:25px
}
```

```html
  
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_f0f28"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 580,
  "height": 310,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_f0f28"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
  <input id="in01"></input>
<button onclick="test()" >search me</button>
```

Comment: You can't access contents of cross domain iframe for security reasons. You can however change the `src` of the iframe to same config that a direct search on bing site does when you search there directly

Comment: Yes, I did it for myself, but it slows down my page a lot@charlietfl

Comment: No idea what causes that. Your only other choice is use a bing custom search api